# Python/Discord: Member does not have attribute server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I found this code online so made a few adjustments to it but it doesn't actually work:

```
if message.content == "Test":
    member = message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, id="Character Created")
    await bot.add_roles(member, role)
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change it with `member.guild.roles` it will work fine. This is the working code:

```
if message.content == "Test":
    member = message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id="Character Created")
    await bot.add_roles(member, role)
```

Comment: If this helped you, you can accept it as an answer.

Comment: There is a tick button under the downvote icon. Just press it.